# tengo ese error con xampp cuando quiero entrar phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']' in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Contexts/ContextMariaDb100000.php on line 120

Comment: Hola, las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas. Básicamente porque es IMPOSIBLE que podamos ayudarte si no pones el código. Te recomiendo las siguientes lecturas: [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour),
[Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
[Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Y cómo están configuradas esas herramientas en tu xampp? Revisa el comentario que te hacen y edita tu pregunta

Comment: es la configuracion de xampp lo instale pero me sale ese error y voy a la carpeta que dice y el erro es este   'LEAVE' => 3, 'LIMIT' => 3, 'LINES' => 3, 'ORDER' => 3, 'OUTER' => 3,
        'PURGE' => 3, 'RANGE' => 3, 'READS' => 3, 'RLIKE' =. 3, 'TABLE' => 3,
        'UNION' => 3, 'USAGE' => 3, 'USING' => 3, 'WHERE' => 3, 'WHILE' => 3,
        'WRITE' => 3, quiero cambiarlo y no se puede estoy desde una mac

Comment: donde dice RLIKE=.3

Comment: Cambialo desde la terminal con sudo: `sudo nano /la/ruta/del/archivo`

Comment: Por favor, si debes añadir información y aclarar detalles de la pregunta, ponlo todo EN la pregunta. En los comentarios a veces es muy difícil revisar código y fragmentos de archivos. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].